# Would it be okay to post a question for friendly competition?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, appropriate-questions, community-wiki

I recently asked about the origin of "P.U." in relation to something smelly.  It seems likely that it is not actually an acronym, and I thought it might be fun to post a 'competition' to come up with the best suggestion for what P.U. *ought* to stand for.  In other words, let's make it into a backronym!  Can we do this as a community wiki?  Please?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: downvotes on meta basically mean "I disagree" rather than "This question is useless or unclear". (This is not a hard-and-fast rule, just a convention that has established itself over the years, across pretty much all meta sites of the network. You are free to not follow it yourself, just be aware that many if not most other people do.)

Comment: @RegDwight Ah, I see. I thought I might have done something wrong by asking the question, but you are saying that rather than voting on the answer, one might vote on the question to indicate agreement/disagreement. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, that's the quick-and-dirty approach. Of course, leaving an answer or a comment is more helpful, but many people just don't have too much time to spend on the metas, so they try to give at least *some* feedback by directly voting on questions. And the rep implementation actually encourages that in a way — note how you only have "ghost" rep here. That is, whether you are getting upvoted or downvoted doesn't change your privileges; it basically gives you some quick straw-poll results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is something that would certainly be appropriate in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).  The EL&U chat is actually quite active and fun, so I recommend bringing it up there.

In the main EL&U site, though, I don't think it will work.  The closest thing to a "game" question that has been allowed on EL&U is one with an objective answer: e.g. "What's the longest English word that doesn't reuse any letters", and things like that.

Comment: Well, I was holding out for what I *wanted* to hear, but I guess the hordes are against me!  Thanks.  I'll bring it up in chat.